# Haskell - Aeson : Getting "Nothing" when trying to decode JSON URL Req

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I'm relatively new to haskell and right now I'm trying to get a deeper understanding and trying to get used to different popular libraries.

Right now I'm trying "aeson".

What I want to do is parse MSFT quote request from https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

This is what it looks like

```
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "MSFT",
        "02. open": "105.3500",
        "03. high": "108.2400",
        "04. low": "105.2700",
        "05. price": "107.6000",
        "06. volume": "23308066",
        "07. latest trading day": "2018-10-11",
        "08. previous close": "106.1600",
        "09. change": "1.4400",
        "10. change percent": "1.3564%"
    }
}
```

This is what I've got so far

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import           GHC.Exts
import           GHC.Generics
import           Network.HTTP
import           Network.URI

jsonURL :: String
jsonURL = "http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo"

getRequest_ :: HStream ty => String -> Request ty
getRequest_ s = let Just u = parseURI s in defaultGETRequest_ u

jsonReq = getRequest_ jsonURL

data Quote = Quote {quote         :: String,
                    symbol        :: String,
                    open          :: Float,
                    high          :: Float,
                    low           :: Float,
                    price         :: Float,
                    volume        :: Float,
                    ltd           :: String,
                    previousClose :: Float,
                    change        :: Float,
                    changePerct   :: Float
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Quote
instance ToJSON Quote


main :: IO ()
main = do
  d <- simpleHTTP jsonReq
  body <- getResponseBody d
  print (decode body :: Maybe Quote)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Fixed version in the answers.

Comment: The derived instance probably expects a single object with 11 keys, not a 1-key object whose value has 10 fields.

Comment: Also, the derived field names are your accessors (like `quote`, `symbol`, etc), not the actual JSON keys like '"Global Quote"' and '"01. symbol"'. You'll need to write your instances by hand.

Comment: Some fields don't have proper types. For example, the prices are double-quoted strings in your JSON example, whereas numbers (`Float`) are encoded without double-quotes in JSON. Have you tried writing a decoder by hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: Aeson is *not the easiest library for a beginner*. There are more difficult ones, sure, but it supposes you already a fair number of things about the language. You didn't pick the "simplest task" to begin with. I know this can be surprising, and you might think that parsing JSON should be simple, but parsing JSON with strong type guarantees is actually not that simple.

But here's what I can tell you to help you a bit:

- First, use `eitherDecode` rather than `decode`: you will get an error message rather than simply `Nothing`, which will help you a bit.
- Deriving through `Generic` is neat and very often, a time saver, but it's not magic either. The name of the object key and the name of your datatype fields have to match exactly. Sadly, this is not the case here and due to haskell syntax, you couldn't name your fields like the keys of the object. Your best solution is to implement FromJSON manually (see the recommended link below). A good way to see "what is expect" by the generic FromJSON is to also derive ToJSON, create a dummy `Quote` and see the result of `encode`.
- Your first field (`quote`) is not a key of the object itself, but rather the name of this object. So you have dynamic keys ("Global Quote" being one here). Once again, this typically a case where you want to write the FromJSON instance manually.

I recommend you read this famous [tutorial written by Artyom Kazak](https://artyom.me/aeson) on Aeson. This will help you tremendously and is probably the best advice I can give.

For your manual instance, supposing it was *exactly* the document you want to parse and you had only the "Global Quote" to deal with, it would look more or less like this:

```
instance ToJSON Quote where
  parseJSON = withObject "Document" $
    \d -> do
        glob <- d .: "Global Quote"
        withObject "Quote" v (\gq ->
          Quote <$> gq .: "01. symbol"
                <*> pure "Global Quote"
                <*> gq .: "02. open"
                <*> gq .: "03. high"
          -- ... and so on
         ) v
```

(It's not the most pretty way, nor the best way, to write it, but it should be one possible way).

Also note that, as an astute commenter wrote, the types of your fields are not always aligned with the type of your example JSON document. "volume" is an `Int` (byte-limited int), potentially an `Integer` ("mathematical" integer, no bound), but not a `Float`. Your "ltd" can be parsed a string - but it probably should be a date (`Day` from `Data.Time` would be the first choice - it already has a `FromJSON` instance so chances are it should be parseable as is). Change percent is most likely not parseable as Float like that, you'll need to write a dedicated parser for this type (and decide how you want to store it - `Ratio` is a potential solution).

Comment: use "decodeEither" was such a game changer for me, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

@Raveline with their answer above pointed me to the right direction. I was able to solve all those issues, here's the final product!

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}

module Test where

import           Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import           GHC.Exts
import           GHC.Generics
import           Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)

jsonURL :: String
jsonURL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo"

getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = simpleHttp jsonURL

data Quote = Quote {
                   symbol        :: String,
                   open          :: String,
                   high          :: String,
                   low           :: String,
                   price         :: String,
                   volume        :: String,
                   ltd           :: String,
                   previousClose :: String,
                   change        :: String,
                   changePercent :: String
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)


instance FromJSON Quote where
  parseJSON = withObject "Global Quote" $
    \o -> do
      globalQuote   <- o           .: "Global Quote"
      symbol        <- globalQuote .: "01. symbol"
      open          <- globalQuote .: "02. open"
      high          <- globalQuote .: "03. high"
      low           <- globalQuote .: "04. low"
      price         <- globalQuote .: "05. price"
      volume        <- globalQuote .: "06. volume"
      ltd           <- globalQuote .: "07. latest trading day"
      previousClose <- globalQuote .: "08. previous close"
      change        <- globalQuote .: "09. change"
      changePercent <- globalQuote .: "10. change percent"
      return Quote {..}


main :: IO ()
main = do
  d <- (eitherDecode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Either String Quote)
  case d of
    Left e   -> print e
    Right qt -> print (read (price qt) :: Float)
```